# Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModuleV4" in its module list

Tags: c#, .net, api, iis, .net-core

I am deploying .NET Core APIs on IIS.
That time gave me this type of error.

> Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModuleV4" in its
>   module list

I created those APIs using **.NET Core 3.0**.

Any help me to solve this issue.

[image: screenshot 1]

Thanks :)

Comment: Your mistake is that you manually changed `AspNetCoreModuleV2` to `AspNetCoreModuleV4` in `web.config`. There is no v4 yet, so you can only use v2.

Comment: No, I already tried that.

Comment: You have to run some basic diagnostics to make sure you didn't make simple mistakes, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: Hello @LexLi, Using that link I am not able to solve that issue. Can you explain in more details?

Comment: I wrote Jexus Manager to scan IIS/IIS Express to identify typical mistakes. So you have to download and install that tool to actually run the diagnostics.

Comment: I suggest you could firstly try to make sure you have installed the 3.0 runtime by using this command: dotnet --info. If you don't install the 3.0 runtime , you could download it from this [url](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0).  Besides, I suggest you could try to post the details error message if you modify the moudule to AspNetCoreModuleV2.